# How can I change the default branch of a contributed module?

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

If you're more used to GitLab than Drupal.org, you might spend a while hunting through settings there to figure out how to change the default branch - or concluding that you simply can't.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's a setting on your Drupal.org version of the module page. Visit `edit > default branch` on the page-specific menu of your module.

At the time of creating this question, the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1659588) from 2012 (last updated 2015) is still close enough to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal.org removed the possibility to delete a branch from the project page. Project owners who edit a project they created will see the following tabs.

> [image: screenshot]

The tab to change the default branch isn't anymore shown.

Instead, Project owners need to visit the Gitlab repository from the browser. The *Repository > Branches* page lists all the branches, with a button to delete them. As long as a branch isn't the default one, it can be delete.

> [image: screenshot]

To change the default branch, is sufficient to visit the *Settings > Repository* page. The *Branch defaults* section, once expanded, allows to change the default branch, which is necessary to delete a branch that is set as default.

> [image: screenshot]